Compare strings from a very large text file (over 100 GB) with a small text file (about 30 lines) and print all the strings contained in both files
I have two text files. One contains a very long list of strings (100 GB), the other contains about 30 strings. I need to find which lines in the second file are also in the first file and write them to another,third text file. Manually searching for each line is a pain, so I wanted to write a  script to do it automatically.
For this I choose Python because it is the only language that I know even a little.
Essentially I tried copying this answer since I'm too inexperienced to write my own code: Compare 2 files in Python and extract differences as a strings
smallfile = 'smalllist.txt'
bigfile = 'biglist.txt'



def file_2_list(file):
    with open(file) as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        lines = [line.rstrip() for line in lines]
        return lines


def diff_lists(lst1, lst2):
    differences = []
    both = []
    for element in lst1:
        if element not in lst2:
            differences.append(element)
        else:
            both.append(element)
    return(differences, both)


listbig = file_2_list(bigfile)
listsmall = file_2_list(smallfile)

diff, both = diff_lists(listbig, listsmall)

print(both)

I wanted it to print me the lines that are in both lists.
However it gave me a "memory error". But I'm already using a 64-bit version of Python, so the memory limit shouldn't be an issue? (I have 16 GB RAM)
So how can you avoid this “memory error”? Or maybe there is a better way to accomplish this task?

How do you think loading over 100 GB with only 16 GB RAM shouldn't be an issue?

Do you really want to print them in list format? That seems both unusual and inconvenient for further use. How often do the strings occur in the large file? Do you care about their order? Do you care about how often they occur?

The file.readlines method reads the entirety of a file into memory, which you should avoid when the file is that large.
You can instead read the lines of the smaller file into a set, and then iterate over the lines of the larger file to find the common lines by testing if a line is in the set:
def common_lines(small_file, big_file):
    small_lines = set(small_file)
    return [line for line in big_file if line in small_lines]

with open(smallfile) as file1, open(bigfile) as file2:
    both = common_lines(file1, file2)


Fun version that might be faster and save lots of memory if the lines occur often: d = {line: line for line in small_file} and then list(filter(None, map(d.get, large_file))).
